# Access ubuntu machine behind WIFI router using local domain name

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

I have an ubuntu machine connected behind a WIFI router which is connected to the internet. I have setup bind9 DNS on my ubuntu machine and assigned a local domain name "myserver.cloud".

I am able to ping or resolve the domain from within my ubuntu machine itself. However, this doesn't work when I try to ping it from my windows machine which is on the same network using domain name. I can connect to it using ip address but not the domain name.

Any ideas how can I resolve it?

**UPDATE**

I can access the machine through my browser using hostname (http://hostname) but not using the domain name that I have setup

Comment: The most easiest way is to edit the Windows' hosts file. Otherwise you must setup the LAN connection of the widows machine to use your bind9 DNS service instead the one provided by the router (ISP) or you can setup the the router to provide your bind9 DNS via its DHCP.

Comment: @pa4080 How do I setup router to provide DNS via DHCP? How will my internet work then? Are you suggesting me to use another router?

Comment: @pa4080 I am not using Windows hosts file as the server will be connected to any device which is on the network, may it be a computer, or a phone.